# Good way to center evenly margin divs within container?

Tags: css, css-float

What I'm trying to do is center an x amount of divs within a container, and have a margin on each side of the divs of 14px

But, code like this:

```
divs{
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 7px;
}
```

Will produce a margin of 7px on the outside of the two outer divs, along with the even margins on the inner side of each div. What is generally good practice to combat this? I was thinking apply a 'last' class to the last div and give it margin-right: 0, while the rest have margin-right: 14, but that seems messy.

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ZMqbW/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Suggestion #1**

What prevents you from adding a padding to the container?

```
.container {
    padding: 7px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.divs {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 7px;
}
```

Also please note, that Internet Explorer doesn't like inline-block too much, so I'm using `float: left;` in combination with `overflow: hidden;` on the container.

You can [**try this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/baqKm/) and see if it works for you.

**Suggestion #2**

Another suggestion would be to use pseudo-classes like so:

```
.divs:first-child {
    margin-left: 14px;
}
​.divs:last-child {
    margin-right: 14px;
}​​​​​​​​​​
```

Try [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/e6jU8/) to see it in action.

Comment: container already has a padding - like say #content, which has set padding of 15px. I was trying to do this without wrapping everything in more containers. I see what you mean, thanks; I'll try it.

Comment: I don't think that works in my situation. Realistically, there is more than just .container and .divs on my page. There is a content area which already has a padding, and if I apply 7px to that, then I would have to apply 7px margin to every element within that container, no? Or wrap everything except the elements I'm trying to center and margin above.

Comment: I don't see why would you want to mix various elements within the same container. If the idea of a padding somehow doesn't apply to your case, you can try my second suggestion with pseudo-classes.

Comment: I don't understand how I could do this without that? If these elements are within a #content, like say a blog - #content, which has a set padding, as per given, then to center the divs as I explained above, in that #content would require psuedo classes? What is the preferred method in this instance? Maybe don't set padding on #content?

Comment: You can see similar situation on stackoverflow - see sidebar, has .module divs which have padding set. now how would you center 3 items evenly spaced and align with the dimensions of those modules?

Comment: You don't need to apply pseudo-classes to *center* your divs. You can use `text-align:center;` on the container for that.

Comment: No, I'm not just looking to center them, I'm looking to center them and have them align with the container dimensions.

Comment: Can you provide your html structure please (as a fiddle for example)? Also, do your container and inner divs have variable or fixed width?

Comment: So what is the issue? Just apply 7px padding to the module and 7px margin to <li>. That will give you even spacing without affecting the sidebar.

Comment: What? No, all modules have that padding set. If I change that to 7px, then the rest of the modules will be misaligned won't they because they don't have 7px matching margin.

Comment: I'll try out what you suggested anyway. Maybe I have to rethink whole way of structuring document first. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to change the padding of a *particular* module, why don't you add it another class? Like `class="module special"` and apply that 7px padding to the `special` class?

Comment: Then pseudo-classes are your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is very elegant, but `text-align: center` on the container works for this.

**EDIT**: test http://dabblet.com/gist/2793852

Comment: I don't think it does. Just tried that, and margins on the two outer divs are still present. It centers them, but they are not aligned with the container div.

Comment: You mean the margins on the outer divs? You can use pseudo-clases to deal with those. I've edited my answer to include a link to a test.

Comment: I've edited the demo again - is this http://dabblet.com/gist/2793852 what you are trying to get?